# Value of Thread.currentThread().getName() is a constant value or not?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question related to java thread.

I have a facade class, where I am initialising memory analyser which in turn creates a task_map. Map's key is `Thread.currentThread().getName()`

```
{
  test.startMemoryAnalyser(request, Thread.currentThread().getName()); 
}
```

Once my task is in progress, I am updating the status of the task in the `task_map`. I am trying to fetch the status of map element correspond to `Thread.currentThread().getName()` key, but I am getting `NullPointerException`.

Code to insert data in map:

```
processMemoryMap.put(Thread.currentThread().getName(), requestStatus);
```

Code to get entry to update status:

```
Status s = processMemoryMap.get(Thread.currentThread().getName());
s.update(); //Throwing null pointer exception Both are called from same handler class.
```

As both method is called from same class, I expect to get the status which I have placed in above scenario, but I am getting `null`.

Please suggest me your thought. Thanks for your time and help in advance :-)

Comment: "trying to fetch the status of map element" can you the code?

Comment: Threaad.currentThread() and getName() will never return a null, so your error is in code you haven't shown us.  Yes, getName() will be changed if you call setName() but you can't set it to `null`.

Comment: Why not just use `Thread.currentThread()` as a key?

Comment: Some more code would be really helpfull. Especially Where you are inserting into the Map, where you start the Thread and where in the code these 3 Lines you posted are.

Comment: There could be so much things causing your problem: Maybe you are working on the wrong thread, or you are setting the value in the map in another thread AFTER starting this thread and are experiancing a datarace. Generally, you could use the `.containsKey(...)` method on the map in order to check whether the key is set or whether not.

Comment: _As both method is called from same class_: irrelevant here. To work, they must be called from the same **thread**.

Comment: is your map initialized? Show more code

Answer (score 5):

> Value of Thread.currentThread().getName() is a constant value or not?

No, it isn't, for the obvious reason that there is a [setName(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setName-java.lang.String-) method. You have no assurance that the result of [getName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getName--) will be constant, unique, non-null or in any way useful as a key.

For the purposes of the application described above, you probably want to use the [getId()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId--) method:

> Returns the identifier of this Thread. The thread ID is a positive long number generated when this thread was created. The thread ID is unique and remains unchanged during its lifetime. When a thread is terminated, this thread ID may be reused.

**Note that last sentence:** if you are trying to create a task map indexing on the thread ids, you will need to allow for the fact that the ids from dead threads will eventually be reused.

However, if what you're blocked on is a unique key, `getId()` is more likely to be useful than `getName()`.